# Java limit user input with regex

Tags: java, regex, roman-numerals

I need to limit user input of arithmetical operation with Roman numerals.
The only possible input is [I to X][+-/*][I to X].

That is what I have:

```
boolean correctRoman = operation.matches("^(X|IX|IV|V?I{0,3}) ?[+-/*] ?(X|IX|IV|V?I{0,3})$")
```

What I get for different inputs:

```
"III"  //false
"III + "  //true-WHY??
"III + X"   //true as it should be
```

Thank you!

Comment: That is because the last part here `V?I{0,3}` matches an optional `V` and 0-3 times an `I` making the whole parts optional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this part of the pattern `(X|IX|IV|V?I{0,3})` the whole last alternative is optional due to the question mark and the quantifier `{0,3}` allowing to match `"III + "`

Note to put the `-` at the end of the character class or else it will match a range `+-/`

---

You can add another alternation to match `I` `II` and `III` and don't make the V optional.

```
^(X|IX|IV|VI{0,3}|I{1,3}) ?[+/*-] ?(X|IX|IV|VI{0,3}|I{1,3})$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(X|IX|IV|VI{0,3}|I{1,3})` Match roman numerals 10, 9, 4, 5-8 and 1-3
- `?[+/*-] ?` Match one of the characters between optional spaces
- `(X|IX|IV|VI{0,3}|I{1,3})` The same number numbers as the first part
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uFPD8p/1)

Answer (score 0):

The numeral part in your regex is slightly wrong, as it accepts empty strings: `(X|IX|IV|V?I{0,3})`. That `V?I{0,3}` means 0 or 1 V, and 0 to 3 I. So, 0 V and 0 I is valid (an empty string).

Try with `(X|IX|IV|VI{0,3}|I{1,3})`